# jQuery slideToggle make it so that the hidden content starts and ends BEHIND clicked div

Tags: jquery, css

I have three divs: Placard 1, Placard 2, and Placard 3 that when clicked use jQuery slideToggle to reveal hidden data stored in divs #panel1, #panel2, #panel3. This all works perfectly in that:

1. the distance between the Placards is maintained at 15px between each other when the hidden data is not revealed or 15px between the bottom of the hidden data and the next placard when one is clicked
2. When hidden data is revealed, the Placard below it moves down to make room.

The question I have is: How do I make it so that the hidden data that animates down when the Placard is clicked starts and ends *behind* the clicked Placard (15px from the top)?

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#placard1").click(function(){
    $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  
  $("#placard2").click(function(){
    $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
  });
  
  $("#placard3").click(function(){
    $("#panel3").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#box1, #box2, #box3 {
/*   position: relative; */
/*   border: solid 1px coral; */
  margin: 10px;
  width: 410px;
}

#placard1, #placard2, #placard3 {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  border-radius: 8px;
  min-height: 40px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
/*   position: absolute;   */
/*   position: sticky; */
}

#panel1, #panel2, #panel3  {
/*   margin-top: -70px; */
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
  background-color: #eee;
/*   position: absolute; */
/*   position: fixed; */
/*   position: relative; */
/*   position: sticky; */
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1">
  <div id="placard1">Placard 1 - click for more details</div>
  <div id="panel1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</div>
</div>

<div id="box2">
  <div id="placard2">Placard 2 - click for more details</div>
  <div id="panel2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>

<div id="box3">  
  <div id="placard3">Placard 3 - click for more details</div>
  <div id="panel3">quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</div>
</div>
```

I have tried using margin-top: -70px, but that ends up animating the hidden content both down and up. I have also tried combinations of using position relative, absolute, etc.. but can't figure out what I need.

Comment: Doing so makes the animation of the expanding hidden block animate up and down at the same time, instead of just down. See: https://codepen.io/Chris_Nielsen/pen/pmdweZ